# How to build OpenWebRTC NativeDemo app for IOS?

Tags: cocoapods, codec, openwebrtc

I am trying to build the demo app provided by  [EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-examples](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-examples) OpenWebRTC example apps. However, I am running into problems when trying to run (pod install) in terminal. Is there anyone who is facing the same problem or know a solution?

This Is what I get in terminal when running pod install:

`$ pod install

Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading:`OpenWebRTC-SDK`from`https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-ios-sdk.git`
Downloading dependencies
Installing OpenWebRTC (0.3.95)

[!] Error installing OpenWebRTC
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/xg/fyy0qlqs4r3436bby7c5qpqh0000gn/T/d20180713-16655-1849d2e/file.zip https://pods.cct.ericsson.net/OpenWebRTC_0.3.95.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to pods.cct.ericsson.net:443 `

Comment: Did you solve this?